# What is the difference between Route exact prop and NavLink exact prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The Route exact prop meaning that accurately path "rendered to the screen" and not rendered a bit longer similar path. So the second row can also work.

```
<Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Users />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/:userId/places" exact>
          <UserPlaces />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/places/new" exact>
          <NewPlace />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/places/:placeId">
          <UpdatePlace />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
```

But what meaning the exact prop in case of Navlink?

```
<ul className="nav-links">
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/" exact>
          ALL USERS
        </NavLink>
      </li>       
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/places/new">ADD PLACE</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/auth">AUTHENTICATE</NavLink>
        </li>     
    </ul>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per React Router documentation:

> When true, the active class/style will only be applied if the location is matched exactly.

[Reference](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

So the exact prop in NavLink is used for styling purposes while the exact prop in the Route is used for the navigation logic